# C# code registering both IDs as the same input parameter

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I was not exactly sure how to phrase the question, but I have a piece of C# code for a college assignment. I have to basically create an app that shows data from a database. I am pretty far in but I have this final bit of code that I am mostly struggling with.

Before I show you my code let me quickly summarize what the problem is: my Model/View combination register both the Home and Away teams as the same, due to a probable mistake in my code causing the system to be unable to separate them and show the values independent from eachother.

This is my controller.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {

            // create result variable to later on pass it to the view.
            List<MatchDetails> result = new List<MatchDetails>();

            foreach (MatchStats item in db.MatchStats)
            {
                // create new MatchDetails instance
                MatchDetails matchDetails = new MatchDetails(); 

                // make the hometeamID from this instance equal to the ID value from the database
                matchDetails.HomeTeamId = item.Home_Team_ID;

                // look for nation (country) that is equivalent to the hometeamID
                Nation HomeTeam = db.Nation.Single(n => n.Nation_ID == matchDetails.HomeTeamId);


                //make a new Team instance
                Team homeTeam = new Team();

                //make the team name of the hometeam equal to the name of the country
                homeTeam.TeamName = HomeTeam.Country;

                // get matchDetails property, get the HomeTeamFlag property and set it equal to the Flag property in the database
                homeTeam.TeamFlag = HomeTeam.Flag;

                //make home team property equal to the homeTeam variable
                matchDetails.HomeTeam = homeTeam;


                matchDetails.AwayTeamId = item.Away_Team_ID;

                Nation AwayTeam = db.Nation.Single(n => n.Nation_ID == matchDetails.AwayTeamId);

                Team awayTeam = new Team();

                awayTeam.TeamName = AwayTeam.Country;
                awayTeam.TeamFlag = AwayTeam.Flag;

                matchDetails.AwayTeam = awayTeam;

                matchDetails.HomeTeamGoals = item.GoalsHomeTeam;
                matchDetails.AwayTeamGoals = item.GoalsAwayTeam;

                //add the matchdetails item(s) to the result 
                result.Add(matchDetails);
            }

            // pass all results to the view.
            return View(result);
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {

            // Here we create a new MatchDetails object (and through the constructor we also create the sub objects such as HomeTeamStats)
            MatchDetails matchDetails = new MatchDetails();

            // make the hometeamID from this instance equal to the ID value from the database
            matchDetails.HomeTeamId = id;
            matchDetails.AwayTeamId = id;
            // look for nation (country) that is equivalent to the hometeamID
            Nation homeTeam = db.Nation.Single(n => n.Nation_ID == id);
            Nation awayTeam = db.Nation.Single(n => n.Nation_ID == id);
            // this is where you retrieve the real amount of red cards given from the database.
            // fetch the row in question from the database and connect it to the relevant table
            matchDetails.HomeTeamStats.RedCardsHomeTeam = homeTeam.MatchStats.Sum(m => m.RedCardsHomeTeam);
            matchDetails.HomeTeamStats.YellowCardsHomeTeam = homeTeam.MatchStats.Sum(m => m.YellowCardsHomeTeam);
            matchDetails.AwayTeamStats.RedCardsAwayTeam = awayTeam.MatchStats.Sum(m => m.RedCardsAwayTeam);
            matchDetails.AwayTeamStats.RedCardsAwayTeam = awayTeam.MatchStats.Sum(m => m.YellowCardsAwayTeam);
            // Inputting dummy value that we want to test with in our view
            //matchDetails.HomeTeamStats.RedCardsHomeTeam = 10; // the value of 10 is a dummy value, we now have to extract the real value from the database.



            NationPlayerList nationPlayerList = new NationPlayerList(); // new table instance
            //nationPlayerList.Players = db.MatchStats.Where(match => match.Match_ID == id).ToList(); // connect nation_ID to page ID
            nationPlayerList.Nation = db.Nation.Single(n => n.Nation_ID == id); // show single instance (by ID)

            //return View(nationPlayerList); // show created instance
            return View(matchDetails);
        }
```

Below you see the Model accompanying the controller mentioned above.

```
   public class MatchDetails
    {
        //the constructor. here we create the sub objects so that these cannot be null (this can cause errors)
        public MatchDetails()
        {
            // we create a new object for HomeTeamStats (of type MatchStats)
            HomeTeamStats = new MatchStats();
            AwayTeamStats = new MatchStats();
            YellowCardsHomeTeam = new MatchStats();
            RedCardsHomeTeam = new MatchStats();
            YellowCardsAwayTeam = new MatchStats();
            RedCardsAwayTeam = new MatchStats();
            // create the other sub objects here as well (only once is sufficient)
            // YellowCardsHomeTeam
            // RedCardsHomeTeam
            // etc 
            // etc

        }

        public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
        public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }

        public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
        public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }

        public int HomeTeamGoals { get; set; } 
        public int AwayTeamGoals { get; set; }

        public MatchStats YellowCardsHomeTeam { get; set; }

        public MatchStats RedCardsHomeTeam { get; set; }

        public MatchStats YellowCardsAwayTeam { get; set; }

        public MatchStats RedCardsAwayTeam { get; set; }

        public MatchStats AwayTeamStats { get; set; }

        public MatchStats HomeTeamStats { get; set; }
    }
}
```

These snippets were translated by me from Dutch to English so if I left in any Dutch I apologize. I figured it was always better to ask than to have an answer handed to me without knowing how for next time.

Comment: Can you add the typeConfiguration- Ort Mapping-Code? I expect EF, am I right?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean with EF. If you refer to Entity Framework then yes. I used a template for the database setup.

Comment: Do you use Asp.Net Core or Framework?